# How to set gitignore file and license to None and set add "origin" git remote to Yes all at once when creating a repo via Git-CLI?

Tags: github-cli

When I create a new repo using

```
gh repo create My_Repo
```

I am prompted with the following questions

```
? Visibility
? Would you like to add a .gitignore? (y/N)
? Would you like to add a license? (y/N)
? This will add an "origin" git remote to your local repository. Continue? (Y/n)
```

I would like to manage all the 4 questions in a single command.

I tried the following

```
gh repo create My_Repo --public -g No -l No
? This will create the "My_Repo" repository on GitHub. Continue? (Y/n)
```

It gives me the following output

```
HTTP 422: Repository creation failed. (https://api.github.com/user/repos)
gitignore_template is an unknown gitignore template.
license_template is an unknown license template.
```

I tried `gh repo create My_Repo --public -g None -l None` it also results in the same error.

Also I would like to bypass the question

```
? This will create the "My_Repo" repository on GitHub. Continue? (Y/n)
```

How do I do that?

I am looking to give the following answers in a single command

```
? Visibility --public
? Would you like to add a .gitignore? ====> No
? Would you like to add a license? ====> No
? This will add an "origin" git remote to your local repository. Continue? ====> Yes
```

Also, is it possible to include the following in a single command?

```
gitignore = Python | license = None | add to "origin" = Yes
gitignore = None | license = MIT License | add to "origin" = Yes
```

Comment: Or use the API. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-an-organization-repository

Comment: @matt How can I run this via github-cli? I am not associated to any organization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will give you all the 4 options

1. To create a repo with the following options

- --public
- --gitignore None
- --license None
- add to "origin" Yes

  ```
   gh repo create MyRepo --public -y
  ```

2. To create a repo with

- gitignore = Python
- license = None

  ```
   gh repo create MyRepo --public -g Python -y
  ```

3. To create a repo with

- gitignore = None
- license = MIT License

  ```
   gh repo create MyRepo --public -l MIT -y
  ```

4. To create a repo with

- gitignore = Python
- license = MIT License

  ```
   gh repo create MyRepo --public -g Python -l MIT -y
  ```

---

Whenever you want to include a gitignore template select the template and enter the name with TitleCase. Here is a link to all the available gitignore templates -> [Link](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

Comment: It seems the '-y' option may not be needed.